# Create Room No overloaded Method Error

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, photon

I get error when I try to use the `PhotonNetwork.CreateRoom()` function.  I am trying to pass 6 arguments to it.

My Unity version is **4.7.2** and this function is from the photon cloud plugin.

```
CheckPlayerNameAndRoom();
PhotonNetwork.player.name = playerName;
Hashtable setMapName = new Hashtable();
setMapName["MapName"] = allMaps[selectedMap].mapName;
setMapName["RoundDuration"] = roundDuration;
setMapName["GameMode"] = gameMode;
string[] exposedProps = new string[3];
exposedProps[0] = "MapName";
exposedProps[1] = "RoundDuration";
exposedProps[2] = "GameMode";
//Create new Room
PhotonNetwork.CreateRoom(newRoomName, true, true, maxPlayers, setMapName, exposedProps);
```

Comment: It would be helpful to see the error as it's displayed, just copy/paste it..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That simply means that you are passing in wrong parameters to the CreateRoom  function.

According to photons [documentation](http://doc-api.exitgames.com/en/pun/current/class_photon_network.html), there are 3 overloads of the `CreateRoom`  functiom.

```
static bool CreateRoom (string roomName)

static bool CreateRoom (string roomName, RoomOptions roomOptions, TypedLobby typedLobby)

static bool CreateRoom (string roomName, RoomOptions roomOptions, TypedLobby typedLobby, string[] expectedUsers)
```

None of these function take bool or 6 parameters. Always check the documentation when you encounter such problem.

Below is an example on how to uses each method overload.

```
string newRoomName = "AloneWolf";

if(CreateRoom (newRoomName))
{
    //Success
}
```

Or

```
string newRoomName = "AloneWolf";
RoomOptions roomOptions = new RoomOptions();
TypedLobby typedLobby = new TypedLobby ();

if(CreateRoom (newRoomName, roomOptions, typedLobby))
{
    //Success
}
```

Or

```
string newRoomName = "AloneWolf";
RoomOptions roomOptions = new RoomOptions();
TypedLobby typedLobby = new TypedLobby ();
string[] expectedUsers = { "AloneWolf","OtherUsers"};

if(CreateRoom (newRoomName, roomOptions, typedLobby, expectedUsers))
{
    //Success
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your answer I write this code

```html
Hashtable roomProps = new Hashtable() { { "MapName", allMaps[selectedMap].mapName }, { "RoundDuration", roundDuration },{ "GameMode", gameMode } };
    string[] roomPropsInLobby = { "MapName", "RoundDuration" ,"GameMode" };
    RoomOptions roomOptions = new RoomOptions();
    roomOptions.customRoomProperties = roomProps;
    roomOptions.customRoomPropertiesForLobby = roomPropsInLobby;
    roomOptions.isVisible = true;

    roomOptions.maxPlayers = (byte)maxPlayers;
    PhotonNetwork.CreateRoom(newRoomName,roomOptions,TypedLobby.Default);
```

It works people can join game and see max players in room. Again thank you so much good luck.